# AJAX select2 in WordPress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-select2

I am trying to put AJAX results to [select2](https://select2.org) in WordPress. I am new to do AJAX in WordPress.
I put below code in `functions.php` file of WordPress.

```
function get_data()
{
    echo 'Ajax call output:';
    wp_die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_data', 'get_data'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'get_data'); 


function team_scripts()
{
    wp_localize_script('team_script', 'team_ajax_url', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));   
    wp_enqueue_script('Select2', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js', null, null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('Select2', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('team_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/team_style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('team_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/team_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'team_scripts');
```

I put below code in `team_script.js` file.

```
(function($) {
  var states = [];
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function(event) {
      // Check if select is already loaded
      if (!$(this).has("select").length) {
        var cellEle = $(this);

        // Populate select element
        cellEle.html(`<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"></select>`);

        // Initialise select2
        let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            processResults: function(data) {
              return {
                results: data
              };
            },
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

I am getting result like below

[image]

I am getting error in console.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `action` parameter in your ajax call :

```
let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            'action' : 'get_data',
        }
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function(data) {
            return {
            results: data
            };
        },
    }
});
```

The value of action in JS refers to "wp_ajax_**get_data**" and "wp_ajax_nopriv_**get_data**" action names.

Comment: Thanks @FS-GSW. But your solution is not working.

Comment: I'm sorry. I changed my answer, the action attribute must be encapsulated in a data parameter. Please, try the new solution...

Comment: Thanks @FS-GSW. Now your solution is working. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please help me in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043039/tooltip-is-not-closing-with-select2

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your message. Is it still relevant?