# ToolTip is not closing with Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip) ToolTip with [Select2](https://select2.org). My code is like below.

```
$(".volunteer").on("click", function (event) {

    function templateSelection(data_format) {
        if (!data_format.id) { return data_format.text; }        
        var output = $('<span class="tooltip" title="' + data_format.title + '">' + data_format.text + '</span>');
        return output;
    };

    function resultfucntion(state) {
        if (!state.id) { return state.text;}
        var $state = $('<span class="tooltip" title="' + state.title + '">' + state.text + '('+ state.text1 +')</span>');
        return $state;
    };

    var orga_id = $('#orga').val();

    var cellEle = $(this);

    // Populate select element
    cellEle.html(`<select multiple="multiple"></select>`);

    // Initialise select2
    let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    action: 'get_data',
                    search: params.term,
                    orga_id: orga_id,
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {                
                var options = [];
                if (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                    var user_data = '<table> \
                        <tr> \
                        <td>Organisation</td> \
                        <td>'+text[2][1]+'</td> \
                        </tr> \
                        <tr> \
                        <td>Age</td> \
                        <td>'+ text[2][0]+'</td> \
                        </tr> \
                    </table>';                 
                        options.push({ id: index, text: text[0], text1: text[1], title: user_data });                
                    });
                }
                return {
                    results: options,
                    more: false
                };
            },
        },
        templateSelection: templateSelection,
        templateResult: resultfucntion,
    });
});

selectEle.on("select2:opening", function (e) {
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".select2-results__option", function () {
    $(this).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function (position, feedback) {
          $(this).css(position);
          var txt = $(this).text();
          $(this).html(txt);
          $("<div>")
            .addClass("arrow")
            .addClass(feedback.vertical)
            .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
            .appendTo(this);
        },
      },
    });
  });
});


selectEle.on("select2:closing", function (e) {
    $('.select2-results__option').tooltip('close');  // This code is not working.
    $('.select2-results__option .tooltip').tooltip('close');  // This code is not working.
});

selectEle.on("select2:select", function () {
    $(".select2-results__option").tooltip("close");   // This code is not working.
    $(".select2-results__option .tooltip").tooltip("close");  // This code is not working.
});
```

After selection of a value ToolTip is not closing.

I am getting below error message in console.

[image]

```js
$(".volunteer").on("click", function (event) {

    function templateSelection(data_format) {
        if (!data_format.id) { return data_format.text; }        
        var output = $('<span class="tooltip" title="' + data_format.title + '">' + data_format.text + '</span>');
        return output;
    };

    function resultfucntion(state) {
        if (!state.id) { return state.text;}
        var $state = $('<span class="tooltip" title="' + state.title + '">' + state.text + '('+ state.text1 +')</span>');
        return $state;
    };

    var orga_id = $('#orga').val();

    var cellEle = $(this);

    // Populate select element
    cellEle.html(`<select multiple="multiple"></select>`);

    // Initialise select2
    let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    action: 'get_data',
                    search: params.term,
                    orga_id: orga_id,
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {                
                var options = [];
                if (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                    var user_data = '<table> \
                        <tr> \
                        <td>Organisation</td> \
                        <td>'+text[2][1]+'</td> \
                        </tr> \
                        <tr> \
                        <td>Age</td> \
                        <td>'+ text[2][0]+'</td> \
                        </tr> \
                    </table>';                 
                        options.push({ id: index, text: text[0], text1: text[1], title: user_data });                
                    });
                }
                return {
                    results: options,
                    more: false
                };
            },
        },
        templateSelection: templateSelection,
        templateResult: resultfucntion,
    });
});

selectEle.on("select2:opening", function (e) {
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".select2-results__option", function () {
    $(this).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function (position, feedback) {
          $(this).css(position);
          var txt = $(this).text();
          $(this).html(txt);
          $("<div>")
            .addClass("arrow")
            .addClass(feedback.vertical)
            .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
            .appendTo(this);
        },
      },
    });
  });
});


selectEle.on("select2:closing", function (e) {
    $('.select2-results__option').tooltip('close');  // This code is not working.
    $('.select2-results__option .tooltip').tooltip('close');  // This code is not working.
});

selectEle.on("select2:select", function () {
    $(".select2-results__option").tooltip("close");   // This code is not working.
    $(".select2-results__option .tooltip").tooltip("close");  // This code is not working.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<table style="text-align:left;min-width:800px;margin-top: 0 !important;">
                    <tbody><tr>
                    <th style="min-width:100px">Task <a href="/team/?task=&amp;team=turramurra-team">+</a></th>
                    <th style="min-width:150px">Time</th>
                    <th style="min-width:180px">volunteers</th>
                    <th style="width:50%">Comment</th></tr><tr>
                    <td><a href="/team/?task=test-1&amp;team=turramurra-team" title="Edit this task">test 1</a></td>
                    <td>09:00 - 12:00</td>
                    <td class="volunteer" id="1485"></td>
                    <td><p>hello</p>
</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                    <td><a href="/team/?task=test2&amp;team=turramurra-team" title="Edit this task">test2</a></td>
                    <td>09:00 - 12:00</td>
                    <td class="volunteer" id="1486"></td>
                    <td><p>test</p>
</td>
                    </tr></tbody></table>
```

Three state of the issue.

**First** state when I click on `td` and select2 drop down is displaying.

[image]

**Second** state when I hove over a value of select2 drop down and ToolTip is displaying.

[image]

**Third** state when I click on a value of select2 and that value is selected but Tooltip still displaying. I need to `close`, `remove` or `destroy` the ToolTip. I can see an error message in console also.

[image]

I am trying to replicate my issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abufoysal/6uc7msx4/16/). But I am not so expert about jsfiddle that's why I couldn't do it properly.

Comment: Please use [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So, people can run your codes and help to debug easily.

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. How to do that ? I never did that. Even I have some PHP WordPress code. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the link I provided and there is some guide to teach you to make one.

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. I tried to implement Code snippet. But I think it is not enough. Thanks.

Comment: You should try to share some more HTML from your WordPress code.

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. I added more HTML code.

Comment: Can you add some sample data in your table to reproduce the error in the snippet?

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. I added 3 images of the issue. I hope these can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Ah...Can you please add some sample data from your API? You can mask the data with some random string.

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. Here is some sample data `{
  "1": [
    "Matt McClelland",
    0,
    [
      "35-44",
      "Turramurra Rotary"
    ]
  ],
  "7": [
    "tony Mc",
    2,
    [
      "0-17",
      "Turramurra Rotary"
    ]
  ],
  "10": [
    "MatthewMuhammad Foysal",
    1,
    [
      "",
      "Turramurra Rotary"
    ]
  ]
}`

Comment: @ikhvjs. But the issue not in Data. I need to remove the Tooltip. Tooltip is not disappearing after selection of Value. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a **working** snippet (or fixing the existing one) that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu. Actually I don't know how to create working snippet. I tired but failed. Even these codes depends on AJAX call. Thanks.

Comment: You can see how jsfiddle handles fetch here: http://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/3hrupdn1/22/ and in the [docs](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests).

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu. Actually my issue is with Tooltips. Tooltip appear nicely. But it is not disappearing after selection of a value. You can see Third image. Thanks.

Comment: I understand but in order to investigate it would easy to get a real demo and play with it and try thing, this is how it works best for me.

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu. I tried to copy your `jsfiddle` and replicate my issue. But Tooltip is not working here.  http://jsfiddle.net/abufoysal/6uc7msx4/13. Thanks.

Comment: @MoshFeu. Could you please integrate `jQuery UI Tooltip`(https://jqueryui.com/tooltip) with your `jsfiddle`. Thanks.

Comment: @ikhvjs, I created a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/abufoysal/6uc7msx4/16/

Comment: @abuabu, it is good that you create a jsfiddle, but somehow it doesn't reproduce your issue with the table tooltip pop up. I cannot solve it for you. You may raise your bounty to let someone else to help you.

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. I am not so expert about jsfiddile. I am still trying to reproduce my issue through jsfiddle. You can check it now. I already raised my bounty to let someone else to help me. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu, some tips:  if this is very important to you, try to raise to 300 or more. :)

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. I am going to hire someone. Thanks.

Comment: @ikhvjs. Previously I used +50. Is it possible to raise to 300 now ?

Comment: @abuabu, [answer you here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285374/14032355)

Comment: @abuabu if onkar's answer doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu. I was trying in another way. But I am failed. Now I am trying onkar's answer. But this is not working also.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        });
    </script>
```

Try this script. It may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Saeed Ahmed. I would like to `close`, `remove` or `destroy` Tooltip. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500508/how-to-disable-the-title-in-select2

Check the link

Comment: Thanks @Saeed Ahmed. Actually my issue is after click on a value I would like to close the `ToolTip`. Thanks.

Comment: try .tooltip('close'), depends on what tooltip you use

Comment: Thanks @BoBiTza. This is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SaeedAhmed. Your solution is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating tooltip on only one option and trying to close tooltips on all the options. So other options without tooltip are throwing the error `cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`

I've fixed it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvubrn56/2/)

```js
 $('.js-data-example-ajax').on("select2:close", e =>
    closeTooltips()
  );
  $('.js-data-example-ajax').on("select2:selecting", e =>
    closeTooltips()
  );

function closeTooltips() {
  $('.select2-results__option').each(function() {
    try {
      $(this).tooltip('close');
    } catch (e) {}
  });
}
```

Note: You may have to handle more [select2 events](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events).On JsFiddle it takes time for tooltip to showup don't know why. Keep hovering over elements.

Comment: Thanks @onkar ruikar. I am not getting any output if I use your first solution. I am getting error `Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'` if I use your second solution and Tooltip is also not closing. Did you check my jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/abufoysal/6uc7msx4/16/) ? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to register tooltips inside `selectEle.on("select2:opening", function (e)`. You  can register them at top level. Like in this corrected [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgaj4mbu/). If you do it like in my jsfiddle then you won't need to close tooltips yourself.

Comment: Thanks @onkar ruikar. I checked your JSfiddle. But there is no Tooltip. Could you please display and close tooltip in your jsfiddle ? Thanks.

Comment: I tried with register tooltip at top level. But it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: I've fixed it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvubrn56/2/). There tooltip doesn't show up quickly. keep hovering over options till it shows up. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @onkar ruikar. I can't see any tooltip in your jsfiddle. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv4BI.png

Comment: I used your code in this way but it is not working also. https://jsfiddle.net/abufoysal/smd0cw78/

Answer (score 1):

You are calling close tooltip method while it hasn't been declared yet
The correct way of doing this maybe is to create a js event and dispatch it when your select2 is ready.

A simple workaround :)

```
selectEle.on("select2:opening", function (e) {
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".select2-results__option", function () {
    $(this).tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                var txt = $(this).text();
                $(this).html(txt);
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("arrow")
                    .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                    .appendTo(this);
            },
        },
    });
    selectEle.off("select2:closing").on("select2:closing", function (e) {
        $('.select2-results__option').tooltip('close');  // This code is not working.
        $('.select2-results__option .tooltip').tooltip('close');  // This code is not     working.
    });

    selectEle.on("select2:select", function () {
        $(".select2-results__option").tooltip("close");   // This code is not working.
        $(".select2-results__option .tooltip").tooltip("close");  // This code is not working.
    });
});
```

});